# BIGINT mysql performance compared to INT

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find out if my table will get less performant if I change the primary key to BIGINT(20). At the moment, I'm using INT(7) and have about **300.000 entries already with large IDs (7 or 8 digits)**.
I searched a lot already but only found out that it uses more disk-space (which is obvious).

All of my IDs have 7 digits right now, but my customer wants to change to 8 digits. I won't be able to easily change the software in the future, so I thought about using BIGINT(20) now just in case. Would it be less performant if I use BIGINT even though I don't need to yet?

Does anyone with experience doing this have suggestions regarding speed and performance?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

To answer your question: yes it'll get less performant. Obviously, the bigger the type, the bigger the table, the slower the queries (more I/O, bigger indexes, longer access time, result less likely to fit in the various caches, and so on). So as a rule of thumb: always use the **smallest type** that fits you need.

That being said, **performance doesn't matter**. Why? Because when you reach a point where you overflow an INT, then BIGINT is the only solution and you'll have to live with it. Also at that point (considering you're using an auto increment PK, you'll be over 4 **billions** rows), you'll have bigger performance issues, and the overhead of a BIGINT compared to a INT will be the least of your concerns.

So, consider the following points:

- Use UNSIGNED if you don't need negative values, that'll double the limit.
- UNSIGNED INT max value is 4.294.967.295. If you're using an auto increment PK, and **you only have 300.000 entries, you really don't need to worry**. You could even use a MEDIUMINT at the moment, unless you're planning for really really fast growth. (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html)
- The number in parenthesis after the type **doesn't impact the max value of the type**. INT(7) is the same as INT(8) or INT(32). It's used to indicate the display width if you specify ZEROFILL (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-type-overview.html)

Comment: This says everything I was about to.  You have practically no chance of hitting the limit on an INT field unless you're dealing with a LOT of data (which 300,000 entries is NOT).  Also as mentioned here the (7) doesn't really do anything to limit what the field stores.  You've still got a limit of 4.3 billion (assuming you make it UNSIGNED)

Comment: i know about the sizes of int(7) and so on. but i dont use auto-increment in that table, cause the numbers are imported from another database, and they are much longer than 2 characters

Comment: The fact that it's imported doesn't prevent you from using AUTO_INCREMENT - the AI value is automatically set the max value of the PK after a series of insert (and if not you can use ALTER to change it). Now if you do need BIGINT because you can have numbers over 10 digits long (this happens with serial numbers for example), then yes, it'll be slightly less efficient. If you're really really worried and have a huge trafic, you could use a separate (small) auto increment PK and store your BIGINT as a UNIQUE INDEX (but frankly I don't think it's worth the troubles)

Comment: so you think it is not much less performant? did you find a test somewhere? or a link?

Comment: Yes I think in this case the overhead is marginal and you won't notice it. (I'm working with tables with over 40 millions rows using BIGINT for the PK with no problem)

Comment: so this answer could be marked solved, if we would find a citation where someone actually tested it

Comment: I added this to my answer further down, cause these comments here get to long: did anyone actually tested it somewhere? The performance with "only" 300.000 entries and a sub-optimal field-type?

Comment: @rlanvin, 40 million is peanuts. You are only 1% of the size we are **talking about**.

Comment: Correction: Also at that point you'll be over 4 billions rows, you'll have bigger performance issues, and the **4 billion** overhead of a BIGINT compared to a INT will be **one of your concerns.**

Comment: @rlavin: could you add this to your answer please? "In your case with only 300000 rows the overhead is marginal and you won't notice it."

Comment: I feel like this doesn't answer the question well - what if you are expecting to have max 10 million active rows but think its possible your auto increment could be exhausted (rows are sometimes deleted). Your options are to either use INT and somehow recycle old ids (PITA) or just switch to BIGINT. Then how can we quantify the negatives of switching to BIGINT when there is another possibility?

Answer (score 7):

Not wishing to resurrect a zombie, but 'modern' mysql uses the column type serial, which is a bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT - and certainly suggests that mysql will be (or is) going to be optimised for using bigint as a primary key.

Also, rather than using serial, varbinary(16) primary allows for one (we do this) to use uuid_short() for the primary key (not uuid – which is very slow to use as a primary, because it's a string) - which has the feature of ensuring that every record has a key which is unique across the entire database (indeed - network).

But be aware - some coercion’s will degrade bigint to int with bad results. If, for instance, you are comparing a string representation with a big int - you may find that you get false positives. So one must compare using binary... eg

```
where id = binary id_str
```

Personally I would call this an unfixed bug...

Comment: Can you please link a bit more info about 'suggests that mysql will be (or is) going to be optimised for using bigint as a primary key'. Would be nice t have some more info here.