# Query update issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I m just confuse in this Query and i don't know how to solve this if you have any idea about this please help me or helps are definitely  appreciated

I have table structure like this and test column contain 3 value

[image]

```
UPDATE `test` SET test = test -3
```

when i execute this Query the result will be show like this

[image]

```
UPDATE `test` SET test = test -4
```

But when i execute this query the result will not proper save in test column like this

[image]

**0 result required or i don't need any subtract value also**

Comment: Please post table definition.

Comment: well bigint is made for positive integers, so below 0 it starts at the very top again

Comment: @Hajo how do i solve this Query

Comment: @Hajo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9802b/1 This fiddle says otherwise. That is what I thought, but wanted to test it out

Comment: @JustinPihony well such things sometimes depend on the implementation of the rdbms used

Comment: @Samad - It's better to see the table definition. For example, we don't know if the bigint is signed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you are using the `BIGINT UNSIGNED` data type. If you want to store negative numbers, you need to change it to a regular signed `BIGINT` (Also be sure to set it to `NULL` or `NOT NULL` as required):

```
ALTER TABLE test
  MODIFY COLUMN test BIGINT;
```

**UPDATE**: If you actually want to store 0 instead of -4 in your example, you can do so using the `GREATEST()` function like this:

```
UPDATE `test` SET test = GREATEST(CAST(test AS SIGNED) - 4,0)
```

Comment: Thanx for share your exprience @Ike Walker

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely due to the fact that your bigint is unsigned.

[Per the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html), an unsigned bigint is

> A large integer. The signed range is -9223372036854775808 to
>   9223372036854775807. The unsigned range is 0 to 18446744073709551615.

Notice the unsigned range and how it is your number - 3 (4 comes from getting from 0 to xxx15 I believe)

So, you should only need to update your column to be a bigint that is not unsigned (signed) and this should work.

```
ALTER TABLE test MODIFY COLUMN test BIGINT SIGNED;
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to keep the BIGINT UNSIGNED so that you cannot have negative numbers, then you could write a trigger to force a 0, or you could just make your query something like this:

```
UPDATE test
SET test = CASE WHEN test >= value THEN test-value ELSE 0 END
```

Basically, if the value attempting to be subtracts is more than the current value, then just set the value to 0, otherwise perform the subtraction.

Comment: @JustinPihony without trigger is possible

Answer (score 0):

As per this question:  [MySQL: bigint Vs int](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4769416/341547)

bigint's maximum value is 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

You're wrapping around to the highest value when you subtract from 0, since your bigint is unsigned.