# mySql undesired integer saved, different from what is inputed

Tags: mysql

Before I begin, I realize that I can create the random number function with php but for my own reasons it has to be javascript.

I have a function that generates a random number and it gets saved in the database. In order to do so I have so submit it through a form but when it gets submitted, a different integer is saved in the database.

A random number such as:

```
6108784240204841
```

Produces this in my database:

```
-223602981
```

## HTML

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="number" id="number">
        <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

## JS

```
 $randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*1E16);
 $('#number').val($randomNumber);
```

## PHP

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        if (!empty($_POST['id'])) {
            $inputNumber = filter_var($_POST['number'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        };
    };

try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDb;charset=utf8', 'myDb_admin', 'myDb_password');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO user (number) VALUES (:number)');
    $stmt->bindParam(':number', $number);

    $number = $inputNumber;

    $stmt->execute();

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    return $e->getMessage();
};
```

## Database Structure

```
number    
int(100)    
Primary
```

Comment: Number is too large to save...

Comment: There is no int size that i can set in the database to save it? Or even a different way of saving it?

Comment: INT is always 32 bits irrespective of that (100) - use BIGINT if appropriate, or of course varchar

Comment: Use BIGINT, they're 64 bits. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: bigint Vs int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769416/mysql-bigint-vs-int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trying to save a number that is too large use `BIGINT` .

```
number
BIGINT(20)
Primary
```

[Integer Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: It's just `BIGINT`, not `INT(BIGINT)`

Comment: Sorry was racing to type it up.  Sorry.  Actually getting ready to vote to close.

Comment: @Nix I made the changes you suggested and the number 7132156763691455
Gets changed to
783165534